# Matplotlib with heatmap for prediction in Background

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization

I have tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("t.csv")
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(50,70)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(np.arange(len(df.index)),df['real'].values,c=df["colors_real"].values, alpha=0.9)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.hist2d(np.arange(len(df.index)),df['prediction'].values, bins=30, cmap=plt.cm.jet,alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

The dataset needed for the above plot: [t.csv](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/5a573831a0830172b508246cdfb7691f)
I have got the following figure:
[image: output figure]
But I was expecting the figure to be like this:
[image: expected image]

**I want:**
1) Make the circle with `df['real']` values, where the negative value circle is with lime color in the center, and then with 0's value next to it, and later the positive values over all the values as in the expected figure.
2) place the heatmaps or the `hist2d` with respect to the values, negative with Lime color and Positive with Orange color.
Kindly let me know how I can do this. I want to show the output as in the expected figure.

Comment: Is there any answer or comment for what I want to achieve, anybody?

Comment: It's unclear why you would expect the figure to look like the bottom image. Also how would you make a circle with the `real` values by plotting them versus your index? Could you clarify what is on the x and y axis of your *expected* plot? So, if you have your `'real'` values of e.g. `-0.00009 ... 0.00011` on your `y` axis, what is on the `x` axis?

Comment: I tried to implement it with linear way as in my image. If the circle is not possible then linear would work But how to adjust the background to show the heatmap like effect? Is it possible? The heatmaps are prediction values.

Comment: Your background already has a heatmap as the background, but because of the nature of your data (you index range as input, which is by definition never the same number) you only get some bins with two data points in them because of your bin size. You could decrease your bin size but the colors shown would be corresponding to how many occurences are inside your bin, not on negative or positive numbers. You could then try to smooth your histogram to get something closer to your example. But I have a feeling I still don't get what your actual goal is.